# How to reproduce tifffile.imsave with tifffile.TiffWriter

Tags: python, tiff

I have python code doing in principle:

```
import tifffile
data = np.empty((l, m, n), dtype=np.float32)
tifffile.imsave(file_name, data, imagej=True)
```

which produces a tiff-file in a format that works further down the line. However this can be quite memory intensive. Therefore I want to write something like:

```
writer = tifffile.TiffWriter(file_name, imagej=True)
for page in data:
    writer.write(page)
```

This produces a tiff-file too, but the format is different than in the example above.

I believe `tifffile.imsave` is just a wrapper for `tifffile.TiffWriter.write`. What options do I need to use to reproduce the same result with `TiffWriter` that I get with `imsave`

Comment: None of the above code works and actually raises ValueErrors. The ImageJ format does not support float64 data and requires the shape of the data to be known when writing the first page. Try the [memmap](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/90805c33065da10d8e604850a840c3166099f91f/tifffile/tifffile.py#L574-L593) approach with float32. It should work with the ImageJ format.

Comment: @cgohlke sorry I forgot the dtype, will add it

Comment: Using ```writer.write(page, planarconfig='contig')``` seems to work

Comment: I don't know which version of tifffile was used, but `planarconfig='contig'` is simply ignored for the shape (m, n) images and the code raises a ValueError as expected when writing ImageJ files page by page. Use the memmap approach.

Comment: This works:    (I put it in an answer)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
memmap = tifffile.memmap(file_name, shape=data.shape, dtype=data.dtype, imagej=True)
for i, page in enumerate(data):
    memmap[i, :, :] = img
memmap.flush()
```